# popluating multiple id tags

Tags: javascript, html, regex, tags

How can i populate multiple id tags simultaneously.

On my page i have id tags starting with "total_" phrase, like total_1, total_2 etc., is there a way by which i can populate each of them on a single click in javascript.

Should i use regex or parser.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
for(var i=1; true; i++){
  var elm = document.getElementById("total_"+i);
  if(elm == undefined){
    break;
  }
  elm.innerHTML = "Some text here";
}
```

Using jQuery you can do the following:

```
$("div[id^='total_']").html("Some text Here");
```

Comment: Thank you for providing your useful inputs.

Answer (score 3):

If you know how many there are, you can simply loop through the numbers:

```
for (var i=1; i<=10; i++) {
   document.getElementById('total_'+i).innerHTML = 'text';
}
```

If you are using jQuery, you can loop through all elements of a specific type, and look for the id. It's less efficient, but more flexible. It will work even if the numbers are not contiguous:

```
$('div').filter(this.id && this.id.substr(0,6) == 'total_').html('text');
```

(You can of course loop through elements without a library like jQuery, but then it's a bit more code...)

Comment: Thank you for providing your useful inputs.